# Proxying IIS

Tags: web-services, iis, proxy

I'm getting XSS errors when trying to consume a .NET web service and I'm sure I can fix it with a bit of proxying. However, I've never proxied IIS before. Can anyone point me in the right direction for a good guide/tutorial please?

### UPDATE

First off my apologies for being so vague!

I have a website that is calling a web service in order to populate an AJAX drop-down list. When I call the code below I don't get an exception as such, I get an pop-up that gives the message "This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk ...".

**In .apsx file**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DocCategoryDropDown" 
                  runat="server" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="DocCategoryDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged"
                  AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="DocCategoryCascadingDropDown" 
                               runat="server" 
                               TargetControlID="DocCategoryDropDown"
                               LoadingText="[Loading...]" 
                               Category="CategoryId" 
                               UseContextKey="True" 
                               ContextKey="NY"
                               PromptText="Select a Category" 
                               ServiceMethod="GetDocCategory" 
                               ServicePath="tba">
</ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
```

**in C# file**

```
DocCategoryCascadingDropDown.ServicePath = path;
```

If **path** is on the same server as the web site it works fine but if path is not we get the warning. How do I stop this message from popping up?

TIA

Comment: You might be able to get more help with more detail. What's the error? Where are the virtual directories or sites involved?

Comment: Thanks, John. Good Point! I have a web service on a server that, when accessed, is giving me the error "This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk ...". I suspect that this is because the web service goes off to another web service to get some preliminary information before it does it's thing and so IIS thinks that CSRF or XSS is taking place. In order to get around this I was going to proxy IIS so that it thinks that both of the web services exist within the same domain. Is this correct? If so, how do I go about setting up a proxy in IIS?

Comment: You want to edit your question to add that information. Also, make it clear: where do you get the error? In the service? What is the service doing when it gets the error? Then please post the complete exception, along with all InnerException, by catching it, then please post ex.ToString().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After causing a lot of confusion and getting nowhere with this post I decided to commit the cardinal sin of reposting ... I'm sorry but it was the only way to etch-a-sketch the topic as far as I saw it.

Anyway, that didn't seem to get any response either but, through a long and arduous path, I eventually managed to ask the right question and think that I have a solution.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031414/how-to-prevent-cross-domain-issues-by-proxying-in-iis/1037313#1037313) for the answer I have so far.